# Powershell Script Capture Cmdlet Result/Errors

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm writing a small Powershell script (`.ps1` file) to allow some of our users to manage active directory users in a very simple interface.  The problem is, I'm having trouble capturing the result/output from a cmdlet like `New-ADUser` to see if it was successful.

I'm looking for a way to obtain the result of a cmdlet like `New-ADUser` so that I can gracefully tell the user whether or not the user was created successfully.

Just for further info, this is just a small app running a `System.Windows.Forms.Form` and it starts with the command line window hidden.

In the past for some of our tech guys, I've run the little powershell app with the command line open in the background.  That way they see the red error message fly by and can debug, but that won't work for these everyday users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried?

It's not different from your normal error handling. Set your `$ErrorActionPreference` to e.g. `Stop`, and use try/catch to run commands and catch the errors.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

try {
    #Run code

} catch {
    #Handle error objects, which you access with $_
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks!  I'm still a little new to Powershell, and this helps tremendously!